# Swift class with no initializers but with property observer

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I've just started learning swift and have a question about class initializers. Here is my sample code:

```
struct Resolution {
  var width = 0
  var height = 0
}

let someResolution = Resolution()

class TV {
  var res: Resolution! {
    didSet {
      res.width = 1
      res.height = 1
    }
  }
}

var television = TV()
var resolution = Resolution()
television.res = resolution
```

I'm trying to use property observer. When I implicitly unwrap property observer type which is struct, everything works. Otherwise, it says "class has no initializers. I'm confused why should I implicitly unwrap struct. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not entirely clear from your question, but I assume you are asking why you can’t replace this:

```
var res: Resolution! {
```

…with this:

```
var res: Resolution {
```

Your clue comes from the full compiler error message, which you can see by looking in the compiler logs (or the playground console if you’re in a playground):

```
error: class 'TV' has no initializers
class TV {
      ^
note: stored property 'res' without initial value prevents synthesized initializers
  var res: Resolution {
      ^
error: 'TV' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
var television = TV()
```

When the type of the property is `Resolution!`, you’re saying, “it can be nil, but if anybody tries to *read* it while it’s nil, then that’s a terrible calamity and my whole app should crash.” So Swift initializes `TV` with `res` set to nil, and expects you to set it to something else right away.

However, when the type of the property is `Resolution`, you’re saying, “it cannot ever be nil, not ever, not even when nobody is looking.” That means that `res` *must* have a value from the moment that `TV` is instantiated. But what should that value be? There’s no default to set it to. You have two options if the type is `Resolution`:

1. Set it to some default value using a property initializer (which is what it looks like you’re trying to do):

   ```
    class TV {
      var res: Resolution = Resolution(width: 1, height: 1)
    }
   ```

   …or with an initializer, you can let Swift infer the type:

   ```
    class TV {
      var res = Resolution(width: 1, height: 1)
    }
   ```
2. Ask whoever’s creating the `TV` to specify the initial value when instantiating the class:

   ```
   class TV {
     init(res: Resolution) {
       self.res = res
     }

     var res: Resolution {
       didSet {
         res.width = 1
         res.height = 1
       }
     }
   }

   var resolution = Resolution()
   var television = TV(res: resolution)
   ```

Aside: all of this makes *absolutely no sense*, because you’re changing width & height to 1 immediately after the resolution is set (what?!), but it does compile.

So that “synthesized initializers” message from the compiler? Swift will automatically make an empty `init()` for your classes that does nothing, but not if there are any non-optional properties to be initialized. If there are, you have to write your own initializer.

(Note that if `TV` were a struct, then Swift *would* generate that `init(res:)` for you. It does with structs, but not with classes.)

A third option is to make the type `Resolution?`:

```
class TV {
  var res: Resolution? {
    didSet {
      res?.width = 1
      res?.height = 1
    }
  }
}
```

That’s a better choice than `Resolution!`, which is just a crash waiting to happen. Implicitly unwrapped optionals should only be a last resort, something to use in very specific, carefully considered circumstances.

Comment: Thank a lot!  Now I understand what's the deal with "!" and initializers.

Answer (score 0):

Every instance variable must have a value by the end of initialization time.

- If you don't use an Optional, then you must supply an actual Resolution instance here as the value of `res` — and you are not doing that.
- If you do use an Optional, the compiler supplies `nil` as the value, and so the need for a value is satisfied.

One possibility is to write your class like this:

class TV {
  var res = Resolution() {
    didSet {
      res.width = 1
      res.height = 1
    }
  }
}

Now `res` has an initial value: namely, an actual Resolution instance.

But what you are doing is *not wrong*. It is quite common to use an Optional when you know that cannot provide a value for an instance variable at initialization time, but you intend to provide one soon after.

Comment: Reading my book might help: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_initializers